Code for calculating large numbers. Please rate if there are any unnatural parts
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(char* num1, char* num2) {
    int length1 = strlen(num1);
    int length2 = strlen(num2);

    if (length1 < length2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (length1 > length2) {
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
            if (num1[i] < num2[i]) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (num1[i] > num2[i]) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void add(char* num1, char* num2, char* result) {
    int length1 = strlen(num1);
    int length2 = strlen(num2);
    int i = length1 - 1;
    int j = length2 - 1;
    int k = 0;
    int up = 0;
    int sum;

    while (i >= 0 || j >= 0 || up) {
        int digit1, digit2;

        if (i >= 0) {
            digit1 = num1[i] - '0';
            i--;
        }
        else {
            digit1 = 0;
        }

        if (j >= 0) {
            digit2 = num2[j] - '0';
            j--;
        }
        else {
            digit2 = 0;
        }

        sum = digit1 + digit2 + up;
        up = sum / 10;
        result[k++] = (sum % 10) + '0';
    }

    result[k] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0, j = k - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        char temp = result[i];
        result[i] = result[j];
        result[j] = temp;
    }  
}

void subtract(char* num1, char* num2, char* result) {
    int length1 = strlen(num1);
    int length2 = strlen(num2);
    int borrow = 0, diff;
    int i = length1 - 1;
    int j = length2 - 1;
    int k = 0;

    while (i >= 0 || j >= 0) {
        int digit1, digit2;

        if (i >= 0) {
            digit1 = num1[i] - '0';
            i--;
        }
        else {
            digit1 = 0;
        }

        if (j >= 0) {
            digit2 = num2[j] - '0';
            j--;
        }
        else {
            digit2 = 0;
        }

        diff = digit1 - digit2 - borrow;
        if (diff < 0) {
            diff += 10;
            borrow = 1;
        }
        else {
            borrow = 0;
        }
        result[k++] = diff + '0';
    }

    while (k > 1 && result[k - 1] == '0') {
        k--;
    }

    result[k] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0, j = k - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        char temp = result[i];
        result[i] = result[j];
        result[j] = temp;
    }
}

void processLine(char* line) {
    char num1[100], num2[100], optr, result[101];
    sscanf(line, "%[^+-]%c%s", num1, &optr, num2);

    if (optr == '+') {
        add(num1, num2, result);
    }
    else if (optr == '-') {
        int isNegative = 0;
        if (compare(num1, num2)) {
            isNegative = 1;
            subtract(num2, num1, result);
        }
        else {
            subtract(num1, num2, result);
        }
        if (isNegative) {
            char tempResult[102];
            tempResult[0] = '-';
            strcpy(tempResult + 1, result);
            strcpy(result, tempResult);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", result);
}

int main() {
    FILE* file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (file == 0) {
        printf("Error opening file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    int n;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
    fgetc(file);

    char line[204];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
            if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n') {
                line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; 
            }
            processLine(line);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}   

I wonder if the cords continue naturally.
I'm also curious if I wrote the name of the variable efficientl, andabout the role of differ and borrow in the subtract function.
Also, since it hasn't been long since I started coding, I'd like you to let me know if there's a way to modify it in the easiest way possible.

Do you have a question about or problem with the code? If not, your post is not suitable for this site. But https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ can help you if you are interested in code review.

One "unnatural" part is having a program with zero comments in it.

Although your compare seems correct, it would be more useful if it returned 3 values, -1 for less, 0 for equal, and 1 for greater.

3-way compare is more common
Rather than returning 0,1, I'd expect returning -1, 0, 1, for less than, equal, greater than.  Such 3-way results are then useful for qsort(), etc.
Leading zeroes  mess up the length compare.
Consider first skipping leading zeros.
Pedantic: Consider that char may be signed
Code such as if (num1[i] < num2[i]) { makes for inconsistent functionality on systems when char is signed vs unsigned and one of the values is negative.  Better, and more consistent with strcmp() to compare as if the pointers were const unsigned char *.
Non-numeric?
OP's goals unclear if a '-', '+', or other non-digit encountered,

Minor stuff:
Use const
Code should be able to accept pointer to const data.
// int compare(char* num1, char* num2) {
int compare(const char* num1, const char* num2) {

Large numbers could exceed INT_MAX length
Use size_t for array sizing and indexing.
// int length1 = strlen(num1);
size_t length1 = strlen(num1);


Consider:
int compare(const char* num1, const char* num2) {
  while (*num1 == '0') num1++;
  while (*num2 == '0') num2++;
  size_t s1 = strlen(num1);
  size_t s2 = strlen(num2);
  if (s1 != s2) {
    return (s1 > s2) - (s1 < s2);
  }  

  const unsigned char *us1 = (const unsigned char *) num1;
  const unsigned char *us2 = (const unsigned char *) num2;

  while (*us1 == *us2 && *us1 != '\0') {
    us1++;
    us2++;
  }

  // Or exchange the '<', '>' depending on OP's goals.
  return (*us1 > *us2) - (*us1 < *us2);
}

